# How to keep Spark from splitting text files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When using `sqlContext.load` for a multiple text files, how do you keep Spark from splitting each file in multiple partitions? It's not a problem with gzip'd files, I would like it to work the same for regular text files.

`sc.wholeTextFile` would work except reading an entire 100MB file somehow requires 3G of memory, so I would rather use some sort of streaming, since we would sometimes need to read much larger files.

Comment: StreamingContext has fileStream for creating a DStream from files. That could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splittability is a feature of your InputFormat. [TextInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html) has conditional splitability depending on the source (plain text, some compressed text can be split but gzip is fundamentally not splittable).

To get the behavior you want you can just extend `TextInputFormat` as your own `NonSplittingTextInputFormat` and override the isSplittable method to always return false. Then you can load your files via code similar to the way it's implemented in [sc.textFile](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L800):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

class NonSplittingTextInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {
  override protected def isSplitable(context: FileSystem, file: Path): Boolean = false
}

sc.hadoopFile(path, classOf[NonSplittableInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text],
  minPartitions).map(pair => pair._2.toString)
```

Comment: Added the class definition to your answer. It works great. Thanks!